# EF LINQ 'WHERE IN' with 2 field at the same time

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following table:

```
id             (bigint)  
adId           (bigint)  
listId         (bigint)  
listFieldValue (bigint)
```

And I have this search list:

```
List<long> searchListFieldValues = new List<long>();
searchListFieldValues.Add(100);
searchListFieldValues.Add(200);
```

So I use:

```
using (ClearWhiteDBEntities cwContext = new ClearWhiteDBEntities())
{ 
    var adsWithRelevantadFields =
      from adField in cwContext.tblAdFields
      join ads in cwContext.tblAds on adField.adId equals ads.id
      group adField by adField.adId into adAdFields
      where searchListFieldIds.All(i => adAdFields.Select(co => co.listFieldValue).Contains(i))
      select adAdFields.Key;

    MessageBox.Show(adsWithRelevantadFields.Count().ToString());
}
```

But now I need to check two fields at the same time, `listId` and `listFieldId`, so I create another search list:

```
List<long> searchListIds = new List<long>();
searchListIds.Add(11);
searchListIds.Add(12);
```

Now i need to get all `adId` has (`listId == 11 && listFieldValue==100`) and (`listId == 12 && listFieldValue==200`)

I tried:

```
where searchListIds.All(i => adAdFields.Select(co => co.listId).Contains(i))
   && searchListFieldValues.All(i => adAdFields.Select(co => co.listFieldValue).Contains(i))
```

But it doesn't work. Any solution?

Comment: @Grant Winney wrong result.

Comment: @Grant Winney it is correct please consider groupby: where all adId has ...

Answer (score 0):

What about placing the `where` clause before the `group`?

```
var adsWithRelevantadFields =
  from adField in cwContext.tblAdFields
  join ads in cwContext.tblAds on adField.adId equals ads.id
  where ((adField.listId == 11 && adField.listFieldValue == 100)
         || (adField.listId == 12 && adField.listFieldValue == 200)
  group adField by adField.adId into adAdFields
  select adAdFields.Key;
```

Comment: no it return wrong result, i collect each advertisement fields in the table, now i need to know which ads meet all search fields together.

Comment: for understanding, i talk just about listFieldValues, suppose ad1 values are (1,2,3) and ad2 values are (2,3,4), my search is all ads at least have (1,2), your code return both ads, but answer is ad1.